# How can I use tags inside of a function?

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a tag inside of a function. In this case I want to click the button "find" and display the message "You selected the FIND option!" but it doesn't works. Can someone give me a hint or help me? I'm new using PHP. MORE DESCRIPTION: The website shows me the submit buttons "fruit" and "vegetable". When I click the fruit button then the website displays a table with products and one button called "find". If the user clicks the "find" button then the website must display the message "You selected the FIND option"(this message is just for testing). The problem here is when I click the "find" button, the website doesn't display the message.

```
<form action="Supermarket.php" method="post">
        Please choose which one are you looking for:
        <input type="submit" name='fruit' value="fruit">
        <input type="submit" name='vegetable' value="vegetable">
    </form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['fruit'])){
        fruitMenu();
    }
    if(isset($_POST['vegetable'])){
        vegetableMenu();
    }

    function fruitMenu(){
        echo "--------Welcome to fruit section--------";
        $fruits = array(array('Name'=>"Apple",'ID'=>1234),
                        array('Name'=>"Banana",'ID'=>5678),
                        array('Name'=>"Watermelon",'ID'=>91011),
                        array('Name'=>"Orange",'ID'=>1213),
                        array('Name'=>"Mandarina",'ID'=>1415),
                        array('Name'=>"Pera",'ID'=>1617));
        displayTable($fruits);
        echo "<h2>WHAT DO YOU WANT TO DO?</h2>";
        displayOptions();
    }
?>

    <?php
        function displayOptions(){
            echo '<form action="Supermarket.php" method="post">
             <input type="submit" name="find" value="find">
             </form>';
             if(isset($_POST['find'])){
                echo "You selected the FIND option!";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: You mean you wanted an alert message that show 'You selected the FIND option!' why not add a little javascript function in input? try this <input type="submit" value="find" onclick="alert(\'You selected the FIND option!\');">

Comment: `isset($_POST['find'])` will only be true if you've submitted a form element that has the _name_ `find`. You only have a form element with that as _value_. If you change it to: `<input type="submit" name="find">`, it will work.

Comment: @M.Eriksson It didn't work:(  The website shows me the button with the name "find" but when I click the button it doesn't show me the message "you selected the find option". What else I can do?

Comment: Is this code located in the file `Supermarket.php`, which is what you're submitting the the form to and are you calling `displayOptions()` on that page? Please give us some more context and explain where you show this code etc. Too many unknowns to know what's going on.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Yes, this code is in the file Supermarket.php. Let me edit my question to add more code that explains what I am doing.

Comment: Include the edited version in the end as well (where you've added `name="find"` to the button)

Comment: @M.Eriksson There you go. I added more code and more description about what I am doing.

Comment: Yeah, that won't work. You only execute `displayOptions()` inside `fruitMeny()`, which is only triggered if `isset($_POST['fruit'])` is true. `isset($_POST['fruit'])` is only true if you submit the first form. If you submit the form inside `displayOptions()`, then `isset($_POST['fruit'])` will be false, which means that the `displayOptions()` won't be executed at all. Move the condition `if(isset($_POST['find']))` outside of the function so it's always checked. Basically, two inputs from different forms can't be sent at the same time.

Comment: Oh okay! Let me try that! Thank you very much! If I have more questions and if you have time can I ask you for help?

Comment: If you have other questions, then please post them here and either me or someone else will try and help.